# VBScript Isn't Recognizing Speak Command?

Tags: vbscript, speaker

I need help.  I'm trying to make a personal assistant with batch, and for effect, I want my computer to speak.  I've used the speaking code before, even on this computer, but for some reason, when I try to use the speak command now, it doesn't seem to work.  Here's the code I usually use:

```
Set objVoice=CreateObject("SAPI.SpVoice")
objVoice.Speak("Insert Message Here")
```

I don't know what happened, but when I run the script, I get this error:

Line:    2

Char:    1

Error:   The handle is invalid.

Code     89970006

Source   (null)

Please help me fix this error.  Thanks in advance.
BY THE WAY, I do have Speech API, and my text to speech in Control Panel works.  It seems to be the .vbs file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:

```
Set Speak = CreateObject("sapi.spvoice")

Speak.Speak "Text Goes Here"
```

Or, If you want to have it say something you enter you can do this,

```
Dim Message, Speak
Set Speak=CreateObject("sapi.spvoice")

Message=InputBox("Enter text","Speak")
Speak.Speak Message
```